# How to ==1 on a column defined by a variable

Tags: r, unique, data.table

This is an extremely simple question, but again I'm confounded by the `data.table` syntax.

If I have a string representing a column name -- such as `column <- "x"` -- how do I return just the rows that match a logical condition on that column?

In a `data.frame`, if I wanted to return all rows of the table where column `x` equaled `1`,  I'd write `df[df[,column] == 1,]`.

How do I write that efficiently in a `data.table`?

(Note, `dt[x == 1]` works fine, but not if you use a string like `column` representing the name of that column.)

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790743/data-table-meta-programming/15791747) are close but do not seem to be enough to answer this question.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15791747/1492421

Comment: Thanks for the link @RicardoSaporta; that is the link I referenced in the question, though.

Comment: whoops, I missed that link :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dt[get(column) == 1]` seems to work -- is that the most efficient method?

Comment: +1 In terms of syntax that's nice, yes. Or `dt[ dt[[column]]==1 ]` not quite as elegant.  For speed, maybe `setkeyv(dt,column); dt[.(1)]`.  But on just a single column, the time to `setkey` isn't usually worth it since a single vector scan is pretty quick. Unless you're looking up many times in which case `setkey` could be worth it even on only one column.

Comment: This is generally the syntax I use as well.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this:

```
dt[eval(as.name(column)) == 1, ]
```

See section [1.6 of the FAQ](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf) on how one could create expressions and evaluate them within the frame of `dt` (although the FAQ explains it in the context of `j`, constructing expressions and evaluating them is also valid in the context of `i`, as shown above).

Comment: @Arun, They do, but isn't it equally applicable to `i`?  What I did here works, and follows the same patterns.