# Why does data.table group differently depending on whether I pass it the variable name directly or not?

Tags: r, data.table

If I pass the variable `bloodpressure` to data.table, everything works fine.

```
tdt <- data.table(bloodpressure = rnorm(1000, mean=100, sd=15), male=rep(c(0,1)))
strata.var <- with(tdt, get(c('male')))

tdt[,list(
            varname='bloodpressure',
            N=.N,
            mean=mean(bloodpressure, na.rm=TRUE),
            sd=sd(bloodpressure, na.rm=TRUE)
            ),
        by=(strata.var)]
```

I get this result

```
   strata.var       varname   N     mean       sd
1:          0 bloodpressure 500 100.2821 15.13686
2:          1 bloodpressure 500 100.0392 15.02566
```

Which matches the group means

```
> mean(tdt$bloodpressure[tdt$male==0])
[1] 100.2821
> mean(tdt$bloodpressure[tdt$male==1])
[1] 100.0392
```

But if I am trying to do this programmatically, and the variable is stored in another variable (`var`)

```
var_as_string <- 'bloodpressure'
var <- with(tdt, get(var_as_string))

tdt[,list(
            varname='bloodpressure',
            N=.N,
            mean=mean(var, na.rm=TRUE),
            sd=sd(bloodpressure, na.rm=TRUE)
            ),
        by=(strata.var)]
```

I get a different result.

```
   strata.var       varname   N     mean       sd
1:          0 bloodpressure 500 100.1606 15.13686
2:          1 bloodpressure 500 100.1606 15.02566
```

Notice now `mean` is identical (i.e. calculated across the whole sample not by group.

```
> mean(tdt$bloodpressure)
[1] 100.1606
```

Comment: @Arun I don't think I understand the scoping issue ... I have assigned `bloodpressure` to `var`, but this is clearly incorrect/inadequate, and `data.table` is only seeing `var`. I'll do some more reading ... ;)

Comment: I'm not sure yet, but I think you may have discovered a bug here.. Testing. Will write back :-).

Comment: Yes it's a bug, as I suspected. Filed [#875](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/875). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `mean=mean(var, na.rm=TRUE),` with `mean=mean(get(var_as_string), na.rm=TRUE)` and then it should work - otherwise it just uses the numeric vector in `var` rather than the data table column you want it to use (and returns `mean(var)` for both subgroups).

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
tdt <- data.table(bloodpressure = rnorm(1000, mean=100, sd=15), male=rep(c(0,1)))
strata.var <- with(tdt, get(c('male')))

tdt[,list(
        varname='bloodpressure',
        N=.N,
        mean=mean(bloodpressure, na.rm=TRUE),
        sd=sd(bloodpressure, na.rm=TRUE)
        ),
    by=(strata.var)]        
#   strata.var       varname   N      mean       sd
#1:          0 bloodpressure 500  99.58425 15.55735
#2:          1 bloodpressure 500 100.06630 15.50188

var_as_string <- 'bloodpressure'

tdt[,list(
        varname='bloodpressure',
        N=.N,
        mean=mean(get(var_as_string), na.rm=TRUE),
        sd=sd(bloodpressure, na.rm=TRUE)
        ),
    by=(strata.var)]                
#   strata.var       varname   N      mean       sd
#1:          0 bloodpressure 500  99.58425 15.55735
#2:          1 bloodpressure 500 100.06630 15.50188
```

Comment: Not that I know any better, but is this preferable to the `.SDcols` approach I came across and posted below?

Comment: For one it seems more straightforward, so I would prefer that. I just compared the speed and it seems marginally faster too, but I'd just pick whichever syntax seems easier...

Comment: Cheers. I have switched to the `.SDcols` method because it seems to generalise better - at least in my hands ;) - and fixed a similar problem I was having with the `by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

OK. With *much* help from [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790743/data-table-meta-programming), I think I have an answer ...

```
colVars <- c('bloodpressure')
byCols <- c('male')
tdt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean=mean(x)), .SDcols = colVars, by=byCols]
tdt[, list(
    mean = lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x)),
    sd = lapply(.SD, function(x) sd(x))
    ), .SDcols = colVars, by=byCols]
```

The trick is to use `.SD`, `.SDcols`, and the to wrap everything in `lapply`.

Why is it, that, despite searching for ages, it is only after spending a another block of time crafting a question that I manage to find the answer? A question for https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ ...